# How to set up a "Dev repo" (between the prod and the team) on the same account

Tags: github

I already did that but there is certainly a better way to do it.

Let's say, i have an organization account for my company composed of 5 developers.

I can set up a repo into my organization and let all the developers fork it, but i would like a "dev repo" to merge the work of everybody and test it before pushing to the production repo.

What is the best way to do that ? Can we fork a repo into the organization account or only create independant ones ?

Because the only way i found is to create another account "Company_Dev" which fork the production repo "Company/Project", and every developers fork the "Company_Dev/Project" repo, but there is probably a way to do that on the account of the owner right ?

Thanks !

Comment: We do you use a REPO for this? You should use branches.

Comment: Yes i don't use branches because i need to access the code with a browser but maybe there is a way to do it...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a basic misunderstanding in git. You have one repo which you correctly have figured out by setting up an org. That's great. You and your devs fork and work individually in their repos. That's fine too.

Now, if you're the lead developer and you want to see how people are doing you organize all that in the central org repo on GitHub. I.e. devs send pull requests and you pull them into dev branches, you don't have to pull them into master. In your dev branch you can test the merged code and see if it fits your needs. If you don't like it you don't have to merge it with your production and/or master branch.

In git you work with branches to sort out the good and bad stuff. Everything you approve you merge.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice i'll check my oldest topics.
Ok so every devs has a branch on the main repo, i get it but how to do that with a web app ? I mean i need an URL to test the work with a browser, how to set up an URL to a specific branch of a repo ? Is it possible ?

Comment: assume it's a simple index.htm page. In branch `master` it says `God morning` in branch `spelling` you fixed it. Now you open your browser in `master` and check your page: it's still wrong. Change your brnach with `git checkout spelling` and reload your browser and it'll display `good morning`. If you're happy you can go back to master: `git checkout master` and `git merge spelling` and you have merged the commit from the other branch.

Comment: Ok that"s what i thought but it's very dangerous to do that with the prod repo ! Because assume everything is fine on master, one of the devs who forked the repo pull request a feature on branche_feature wich is corrupted but you don't know yet, you want to test it so you checkout branche_feature, during this time, all your traffic will use this corrupted code ! How to avoid that ? That's why i created another repo which is a fork of the prod, but you need to create another github account to do that, is there a way to fork a repo on a same unique account ?

Comment: ah, I see. You obviously want to test that locally. You have a git repo on your production server (which probably runs on master) and you have a clone of that repo on your local machine. You test, merge and push to your remote server. You could even test remotely (not good if dbs are involved) by checking out the dev branch... (hypothetically).

Comment: oh, and you don't need to fork, you clone repos.

Comment: Oh i didn't think about this way interesting ! so if i understand correctly, the devs push on their branche on the prod repo, you pull it to the local clone on a specific branche, merge it if it's ok, then push to the prod (on master). A last question, what do you do with the branche using to add the feature on the prod repo if you previously merged it on your local clone repo and push to master ? You refuse it on github ? Thanks !

Comment: Or you can dirrectly merge it on github forget my last question it was a stupid one... Maybe you could reply your previous post an an answer so i could valide it !

Comment: No, scenario 1: there is one group repo on github and your devs have clones of it on their machines. They create a branch locally, make changes and push that to your group repo. Then you decide if that's a good change and merge it with master and push it to production.

scenario 2: you have one group repo and some untrusted devs (because they could change master). They have forks on GH too. They make changes and push to their fork and then send a pull request. You can merge that into your group repo.

If the devs have access to your repo they can push branches directly.

Comment: you can always delete merged branches via `git branch d name_of_branch`. Unmerged ones can be deleted via `git branch -D name_of_branch`.

Comment: Ok but on your scenario 2, after the devs send their pull request from their fork to the main repo, before merging on master, i need to test their code so i have to pull it (so they had to pull request to a specific branche on the main repo) to my local machine right ?

Comment: you can pull in their request to a local branch, yes. Or you can pull it in to a github branch. Not necessarily into master. You really should read up on Git, man. http://git-scm.com/book is available in many languages. This is not the place to discuss all scenarios in detail. However, it does what you want :)

Comment: Yes i know GIT still kind of magic in my mind, i'll read all of that, however thanks for your help i really appreciate !